# What does "today like olives" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), Steve Dallas about to meet J.J
who is responsible for getting him fired so D'Angelo advises
him:

> D'Angelo: Steve, you'll do what you want, but it can't hurt. He offers
> you an olive branch, so **today like olives**.

What does "today like olives" mean?

Comment: *...so today [**it's in your / our / everyone's best interests that you should**] like / love / appreciate olives.* It's riffing off *If life gives you lemons, **make** lemonade*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand **offer olive branch** means "offering peace" but didn't understand "**today like olives**".

Comment: Today, you must act as if you like olives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a standard idiom or expression in English, but the metaphor is easy enough to understand.

"An olive branch" is a standard metaphor for "a offer of peace".  So if you "like olives" (or even if you pretend to like olives) you will accept the "olive branch".

D'Angelo is saying "accept his offer of peace"